# Trigger contenteditable using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, contenteditable

I'm working on a small administration of tickets. There's a ticket overview and each ticket has an option to enter the "edit mode". Whenever users triggers the edit mode I want the paragraph tag to become contenteditable. However, the angular triggers an error `'contenteditable' is not a known property of 'p'`, so I'm wondering if there's some walkaround or am I doing something wrong?

The code representation:

```
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-content>
        <p [contenteditable]="ticket.isEditMode">
            Some text
        </p>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-button (click)="ticket.isEditMode = !ticket.isEditMode">
            Edit
        </button>
    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `[attr.contenteditable]`. You are accessing the `contenteditable` attribute on the `p` tag, not a custom `@Input` property.

Here is a working Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lhrdzh.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will mark it as correct in 3mins.